# Select words between commas (excluding double quotations) using regexp_substr

Tags: regex, oracle

I'm attempting to return a list of strings from a comma delimited list. However, I still want to return commas in strings where they appear between double quotation marks.

This is my current statement:

```
SELECT 
  regexp_substr('one,two,"three, four five",six,"seven, eight, nine"', 
                '(.*?,){'||(n-1)||'}([^,]*)', 1, 1, '', 2) token
FROM (SELECT LEVEL n FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10);
```

This returns:

```
one
two
"three
four five"
six
"seven
eight
nine"
```

However I need to return:

```
one
two
three, four, five
six
seven, eight, nine
```

My regex is rusty. Is there a clean way to modify my regex to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to use regex for this, I think that it's only possible with a positive (or negative) lookahead, which oracle doesn't support AFAIK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
'^("[^"]*",|[^",]*,){'||(n-1)||'}("[^"]*"|[^",]*)', 1, 1, '', 2
```

or a simpler version:

```
'(^|,)("[^"]*"|[^",]*)', 1, n, '', 2
```

or if quotes aren't desired - wrap it into:

```
regexp_replace( ..., '"', '')
```