# Oracle SQL regex remove text in square brackets at end of field

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a field in an Oracle database where it is formatted in a certain way like so:

```
Some text with <sup>superscripts</sup> [stock #random-number] [dynamic text]
```

I need to remove the texts `[stock #random-number]` and `[dynamic text]` so that I'm left with `Some text with <sup>superscripts</sup>` and then trim the result so no leading and trailing spaces.

I need to do this inside the query and not on the PHP side as I need to use `DISTINCT`.

Everything is dynamic so what I want doesn't necessarily end in `<sup>`.

Comment: can you not use `regexp_substr('Some text with <sup>superscripts</sup> [stock #random-number] [dynamic text]','.*</sup>') `?

Comment: @vkp I was kinda expecting a pattern/expression. I didn't really understand your solution there.

Comment: `'.*</sup>'` matches any text from the start up to the last `</sup>` including it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select words between commas (excluding double quotations) using regexp\_substr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19043169/select-words-between-commas-excluding-double-quotations-using-regexp-substr) (seriously: there are *tons* of questions on SO regarding Oracle and regexes)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Everything here is dynamic so it doesn't necessarily mean that what I want to get ends in `</sup>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the trim, substr, instr

```
 SELECT  trim(substr(your_string, 1, INSTR( your_string,'['))) 
 FROM your_table
```